# Installing Pinterest Tag on Big Cartel

Tags: ads, checkout, pinterest, bigcartel, conversion-tracking

Big Cartel doesn't have an specific page in the coding area dedicated to "Checkout" and Pinterest is asking me to put the Pinterest tag and Checkout event tag on the "Checkout" page for my website, are there instances where people have used the Pinterest tag to track checkout conversions in Big Cartel, if so how?

I have looked everywhere for articles on Checkout conversions and Big Cartel for advertising but i haven't found anything, all of Pinterest articles on this are general and don't specify on installing the Pinterest Tag for Checkout conversions on Big Cartel, and at this point i don't even know if i can.